# I want to see my java output clean in Apache Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I started java with Netbeans. When I run the program, i see different information on the output screen. Is it possible to see only application output? for example:
run-app
Hello Java!
[my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wobeb.png)

I changed the verbosity level to quiet in tools-options-java but the result did not change.
[java verbosity level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gav2e.png)

Comment: Give yourself the exercise of running the code at the command line. With and without Ant. It can't get less verbose

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in NetBeans menubar you have run ,open rung and choose

> Clean and Build Project

[image]

and after the  you have have this result
[image]

now you can run your java project and you have only the output
[image]

Comment: nothing has changed. I tried this too

Comment: you have java project or maven project ??? try to run at use command line